# Force to use style for a selector, no matter where it is in the dom

Tags: css, private

Say I would like to define a numbered circle, that looks like this:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/6QJyX/

```
.number
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 32px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left:8px;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    border-color:white;
}
```

I would like to add importance **to the selector**, so that **no matter in what context the element** is, an element with class number looks the same.

Here's an example of the code breaking:  http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/6QJyX/2/

A way to do this would be to add !important to all properties of the CSS, but I wonder if they could be other solutions, because it is a bit crappy.

I have added the private tag as that seems a bit like code-encapsulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to increase the specificity of the selector.  Other than that there is not much you can do.

```
#id .number
```

The ID selector will increase specificity so that only another ID in a selector will be able to override it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6QJyX/3/

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the specificity of selectors will only lead to [specificity wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) (which leads to anger, which leads to hate, which leads to suffering). I would suggest *de*creasing the specificity of the selector that's causing the problem.

Pseudo code below:

```
.number {...}
.card span {...} // this selector is questionable
<div.number> this is styled correctly </div>
<div.card>
    <span.number> this is styled incorrectly </span>
</div>
```

Why do *all* `.card span`s need to be styled a particular way? It seems as if the second selector is [more like a grenade and less like a sniper](http://csswizardry.com/2012/07/shoot-to-kill-css-selector-intent/)—that is, it targets a blanket set of elements rather than just the ones you need.